# How to set current fiscal year as on load filter in Einstein Analytics?

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, einstein-analytics-dashboards, einstein-chatbot

I have created one Einstein Analytics  dashboard for opportunity and in which i want to set filter on load of dashboard as current fiscal year which will show data of opportunity of current fiscal year only. can anybody have any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an Date Filter in Edit Mode. Then from the top right symbol with the three dots, select "Pick initial values" and set the Date Filter to "current Fiscal Year". Accept and save the dashboard.

Or, if the user is not supposed to change the date range, insert a date filter in the dashboards queries like:

```
q = filter q by date('Date__c_Year', 'Date__c_Month', 'Date__c_Day') in ["current fiscal_year".."current fiscal_year"];
```